# Learning C, basic string reversal function

Tags: c

I am starting to write some functions while studying how to program in C.  In this small function I take a string as an argument and print it out in reverse order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int aLen = argc;
    char *sWord = argv[aLen - 1];
    char *reversed;

    int sLen = strlen(sWord);
    int i = 0;

    reversed = reversed + sLen;    // offset pointer to the length of string
    while (i <= sLen) {
        if (sWord[i] != '\0') {    // check if character is null-terminator
            *reversed = sWord[i];  // if not, let reversed correct address 
        }                          // equal letter.
        i++;
        reversed--;
    }
    printf("%s reversed is:%s\n", sWord, reversed);
    return 0;
}
```

I was hoping to get some tips on best practice or corrections on any errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has a number of issues, the main one being that it doesn't work.

If you want to reverse a string in place then I suggest you write a function just
for that, separate from `main`.   The function will need a temporary variable
and will, for example:

```
swap first and last characters
swap 2nd and 2nd-from-last characters
swap 3rd and 3rd-from-last characters
etc
```

To swap the characters pointed to by `a` and `b`, you would do

```
char temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = *temp;
```

or if you have a pointer and a length:

```
char temp = a[0];
a[0] = b[len];
b[len] = temp;
```

So your reversal function needs to contain one of these sequences in a loop
and the loop must arrange `a` and `b` to point to the correct places.  For
example, here is a reverse function:

```
static char* reverse(char *str)
{
    char *s = str;
    char *end = s + strlen(s) - 1;
    for (; s < end; ++s, --end) {
        char ch = *end;
        *end = *s;
        *s = ch;
    }
    return str;
}
```

---

Then in `main` all you do is call the reverse function with the desired
string:

```
printf("'%s'\n", reverse(argv[1]));
```

Of course it is best to check that `argv[1]` exists first (remember that argv[0] is the program name and argc is always greater than or equal to 1):

```
if (argc == 2) {
    printf("'%s' reversed is ", argv[1]);
    printf("'%s'\n", reverse(argv[1]));
}
```

---

Notes:

In your code, `aLen` and `sWord` are unnecessary. And `reversed` is
not initilaised but is then used in

```
reversed = reversed + sLen;  // See the EDIT below
```

In the line

```
int sLen = strlen(sWord);
```

`strlen` returns the length as a `size_t`, not `int`

**EDIT**

When you declare a variable local to a function, the compiler sets aside a
space on the stack.  It does **not** write anything there unless you declare
the initial value for the variable.  So in your code, `reserved` contains
whatever happens to be at that location on the stack and, as `reserved` is a
pointer, it therefore points to some unknown (unplanned) location in memory.
If you are **unlucky** that location will be writeable, your accesses 'work'
and you won't see the problem (or not immediately - in a larger program you
will probably encounter strange behaviour later on while the code is executing
because your accesses have overwritten something important); if you are
**lucky** and the location is unwritable you will see the problem the first
time you run the program.

The moral is always to initialise variables, just to be safe.  Zero (NULL) is
a good value for pointers.  With C99 you are not restricted to defining them at
the start of a function, so it is often best to define a variable only at the
point where you need it and have a useful value with which to initialise it.

Comment: This code compiles without errors and prints out the argument to the screen in reverse order.  In what way do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: It compiles without errors but not without warnings - the inconsequential type conversion of `strlen()` and the **fatal** use of the uninitialised variable `reversed`. It cannot possibly 'work' reliably with that uninitialised access. When I run it, it seg-faults, which is not at all surprising.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this. I didn't want to come off as disrespectful or ungrateful, considering you took the time to write a lengthy and  extensive response.  I haven't had this segfault on me or spit out warnings when compiling.  This is why I was wanting to know exactly where and why this would fail.  I have more than alot to learn with C and will be studying up on the issues you brought up here.  Maybe when I make some more well informed edits I'll post again :)

Comment: Well, I went back to testing this code and sure enough it just to fail with any string over 9 characters in length.  I still don't receive any compilation warnings/errors had I, I wouldn't have even bothered with posting this.  Embarassing but, I should learn plenty from your post and the others.

Comment: It depends upon the compiler. I tried `gcc` and it doesn't give me a warning; `clang` with -Wall does. `clang` is often better than `gcc` in this respect.  I will update my answer to give a little more detail on the error...

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate storage for the reversed string using `malloc` unless that's changed in the last twenty years and place a `'\0'` string terminator at the end.

```
char *reversed = malloc(sLen + 1);
reversed[sLen] = '\0';
```

Also, you're writing to cells 1 .. `sLen` when you should be writing to 0 .. `sLen - 1`.

Comment: I will check on the these points you brought up, I appreciate the help.

Comment: You don't need to allocate any memory to do an *in-place* reversal of a string - and it looks kind of like that's what's being attempted.

Comment: @asveikau - I thought so as well until I saw this: `reversed = reversed + sLen;`.

Answer (score 2):

For simply reversing the string, you could do it without allocating additional memory:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc==2){
        char *message=argv[argc-1];
        size_t offsetLength=strlen(message);
        char *last=message+(offsetLength);
        while(last-- > message){
            putc(*(last), stdout);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is allocating memory `malloc` only for resource heavy situations?

Comment: You can allocate memory in the heap using `malloc` or on the stack by declaring a sized array. It doesn't need to involve "resource heavy situations." You can allocate a single byte on the stack using `byte b` (if the compiler doesn't inline it into a register).

Comment: There is one clear answer: it depends ;) No, it is not only for ressource-heavy-situations. Yes, in some use-cases as the one above, there is no need for allocating extra memory. To make it a bit clearer: if you want to preserve the original and work with a copy, it makes sense to dynamically allocate memory needed.